# Create PDPage with right format using PDFBox

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I'm trying to write a simple method that creates a new `PDDocument` and adds `PDPage` with the right page format as supplied by user inputs.

**Input from User can be one of the following:**

```
"A4-Portrait"
"A4-Landscape"
"A3-Portrait"
"A3-Landscape"
```

**Expected output:**
If input is "A3-Landscape" , return `PDPage` with this format.

while I can see ways to create `PDPage` in A3 format using

```
PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A3);
```

Can you help how efficiently and easily can I choose the right format and its orienatation dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
PDRectangle A4L = new PDRectangle(PDRectangle.A4.getHeight(), PDRectangle.A4.getWidth());
```

Comment: This helps, Can we also add page margins while creating a `PDRectangle` or a `PDPage` ?

Comment: That's a different question; it's your decision where you write, i.e. you have to manage this yourself. There is no such thing as a "margin" in PDFBox or in the PDF specification. (There is media box and crop box, but that's something different)

Comment: Can you guide me to the existing question or some guide on how best we can manage the margins. (I'm new to `PDFBox` and media box , crop box are newer terms for me.

Comment: Not really; you'll likely want to show characters at some place in the PDF. Your job as a developer would be to start from the offset you want, and to also stop there. One important hint: PDF coordinates have (0,0) at the bottom left. A good start about showing text is `EmbeddedFonts.java` in the examples subproject in the source code download.